# Error saving custom class in NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm making a simple list of custom items that must be saved in NSUserDefault

```
     import UIKit

    @objc(Oggetto_ordinabile)
    class Oggetto_ordinabile: NSObject,NSCoding {

        var Nome_ita = ""
        var numero:Int = 0
        var Nome_internazionale = ""
        var Immagine:UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "new_drink_placeholder")
        var Descrizione_ita = ""
        var Descrizione_internazionale = ""
        var Prezzo:Double = 0.0


        required convenience init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
            self.init()

            self.Nome_ita = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Nome_ita") as! String
            self.Nome_internazionale = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Nome_internazionale") as! String
            self.Immagine = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Immagine") as! UIImage
            self.Descrizione_ita = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Descrizione_ita") as! String
            self.Descrizione_internazionale = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Descrizione_internazionale") as! String
            self.Prezzo = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Prezzo") as! Double
        }


        func encode(with coder: NSCoder)  {
            coder.encode(Nome_ita, forKey: "Nome_ita")
            coder.encode(Nome_internazionale, forKey: "Nome_internazionale")
            coder.encode(Immagine, forKey: "Immagine")
            coder.encode(Descrizione_ita, forKey: "Descrizione_ita")
            coder.encode(Descrizione_internazionale, forKey: "Descrizione_internazionale")
            coder.encode(Prezzo, forKey: "Prezzo")
        }
    }
```

then i have a method that decides if the info are available and load them from memory

```
private func ScaricaInformazioni(Cosa_scaricare:String){


            if let dati = ValoriDefault.data(forKey: Cosa_scaricare),
                let ArrayArticoli = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: dati) as? [Oggetto_ordinabile]
                {
                 print("Info disp")
                self.CosaVisualizzare = ArrayArticoli
                self.Collection_view.reloadData()

            }

            else{// ancora non sono stati creati i dati
                print("Info non disp")
                switch Cosa_scaricare {

                case "Stuzzichini":
                    CreaStuzzichiniDefault()
                    ScaricaInformazioni(Cosa_scaricare: Cosa_scaricare)
                    break

                case "Bevande":
                    CreaBevandeDefault()
                    ScaricaInformazioni(Cosa_scaricare: Cosa_scaricare)
                    break

                case "Narghilè":
                    CreaNarghileDefault()
                    ScaricaInformazioni(Cosa_scaricare: Cosa_scaricare)
                    break

                default:
                    break
                }
            }

        }
```

if not they are created like so:

```
let BlackRussian = Oggetto_ordinabile()
    BlackRussian.Nome_ita = "Black Russian"
    BlackRussian.Nome_internazionale = "Black Russian"
    BlackRussian.numero = 9
    BlackRussian.Descrizione_internazionale = "Vodka,Kaula"
    BlackRussian.Descrizione_ita = "Vodka,Kaula"

    let PinaColada = Oggetto_ordinabile()
    PinaColada.Nome_internazionale = "Piña Colanda"
    PinaColada.Nome_ita = "Piña Colanda"
    PinaColada.numero = 10
    PinaColada.Descrizione_ita = "Rum Bianco, Succo d'Ananas, Sciroppo di Cocco"
    PinaColada.Descrizione_internazionale = "White Rum, Pineapple Juice, Coconout Sirup"

    var Drink = [Oggetto_ordinabile]()

    Drink.append(Capirina)
    Drink.append(JapaneseSliper)
    Drink.append(Kir)
    Drink.append(ScrewDriver)
    Drink.append(AcquaMarina)
    Drink.append(TurquoiseBlue)
    Drink.append(FrenchKiss)
    Drink.append(LongIsland)
    Drink.append(BlackRussian)
    Drink.append(PinaColada)

    let datiCodificati = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: Drink)
    ValoriDefault.set(datiCodificati, forKey: "Bevande")

    return
```

I'm getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" randomly in the convenience init method, Why?

Comment: If you add an exception breakpoint you should be able to see the exact line where the app crashes.

Comment: 1^st block of code , Oggetto_ordinabile class, required convenience init method, randomly between 1^st to last variable

Comment: What happens if you call super.init(coder:) instead of self.init()?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri posted the code below

Comment: self.init(coder:) causes a crash because you go into an infinite loop. You have to call super.init(coder:).

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri i trashed the code, i saved the Objects as NSDictionary that are allowed in NSUserDefault an then i used a method to convert them back to Objects, thnx anyway :)